# Jquery multiselect and data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need help, to show in multiselect input data from mysql table, I can't understand how. I've got: 
jquery multiselect script wich looks like:

```
$('select[multiple]').multiselect();

$('select[multiple]').multiselect({
    columns: 4,
    texts: {
        placeholder: 'Select options'
    }
});

$('select[multiple]').multiselect('reload');

$('select[multiple]').multiselect( 'loadOptions', [{
    name   : 'Option Name 1',
    value  : 'option-value-1',
    checked: false,
    attributes : {
        custom1: 'value1',
        custom2: 'value2'
    }
},{
    name   : 'Option Name 2',
    value  : 'option-value-2',
    checked: false,
    attributes : {
        custom1: 'value1',
        custom2: 'value2'
    }
}]);
```

and input

```
   <select name='dl' size="1" class="form-control" multiple></select>
```

with mysql request

```
$dq = ("select * from defects");
```

and variable looks like

```
foreach ($dresult as $drow) {
$dnum[] = $drow['num'];
}
```

where table structure include only three columns: num,name and group. 
Finaly i want to get in multiselect something like: num - name and would be awesome if it be included into groups from group column but it is not important. 
[I use this source](https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect) and [Demo](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?N8CC19tH)